# Empty object returned from ScriptApp.newTrigger wihin Google AppScript

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-forms

I am attempting to create a new trigger upon the submission of a Google Form as specified within the AppScript documentation:

[ScriptApp.newTrigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newTrigger(String))

```
function onFormSubmit() {

  const triggerName = 'myNewTrigger';
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  const trigger = ScriptApp.newTrigger(triggerName);

  console.info(trigger);

  trigger.forSpreadsheet(sheet).onFormSubmit().create();

}

function myNewTrigger(e) {

  // perform some task

}
```

When calling 'ScriptApp.newTrigger', I expect an instance of TriggerBuilder to be returned, that includes the method 'forSpreadsheet'.

Instead, an empty object (i.e. absolutely no properties or methods) is returned in its place but is still reported as being an instance of ScriptApp.TriggerBuilder within Google's Stackdriver logging.

```
Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property forSpreadsheet on object ScriptApp.TriggerBuilder
```

Am I missing something fundamental here?

Edit: Thanks to @TheMaster for their suggestion. As `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` was returning `null` due to the fact that it was being triggered with the context of a form instead of a spreadsheet.

By changing this to `FormApp.getActiveForm().getDestinationId()` I was able to retrieve the correct document id for the linked spreadsheet.

Comment: `Instead, an empty object`. If  you're `console.info()`ing, that'll show as a empty object. But it's a object with all properties of TriggerBuilder. Try using the Spreadsheet Id instead.

Comment: @TheMaster Thanks for your suggestion. Your solution not only worked, but I believe I now understand why as well.One thing though, why does logging TriggerBuilder to the console results in an empty object? Is this something to do with how AppScript implements this object?

Comment: Because TriggerBuilder is a object. But it's `toString()` may be overridden. You can try looping over them using [`for...in` or `in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)

Comment: Have you solved your issue? If so please post it as an answer and mark it as correct so more people can benefit from it. See https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @TheMaster for their suggestion. As SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() was returning null due to the fact that it was being triggered with the context of a form instead of a spreadsheet.

By changing this to FormApp.getActiveForm().getDestinationId() I was able to retrieve the correct document id for the linked spreadsheet.