# Please Help! Macro trigger isnt firing properly (onformsubmit)

Tags: google-apps-script, eventtrigger

I have a google sheet with 2 pages.

1st page is a regular table. 2nd page is form submission sheet.

On page 1, there is a macro that is currently activated by pushing a button (code below). (it copies row 1 and inserts a new one below).

```
function Addrow() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  spreadsheet.getRange('8:8').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().insertRowsAfter(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getLastRow(), 1);
  spreadsheet.getActiveRange().offset(spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumRows(), 0, 1, spreadsheet.getActiveRange().getNumColumns()).activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('8:8').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_NORMAL, false);
  spreadsheet.getRange('P9').activate();
  spreadsheet.getActiveRangeList().setValue(new Date());
};
```

I'd like the macro on page 1 to run every time there is a form submission (trigger code below).

Once that works i'd eventually like the first script to retrieve the data from the 2nd column in the form submission sheet and paste it into the third column of the newly inserted row on sheet 1.

Trigger code:

```
function onFormSubmit() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

Logger.log(ss);

ScriptApp.newTrigger("Addrow")
  .forSpreadsheet(ss)
  .onFormSubmit()
  .create();
}
```

The error is:

> Exception: Unexpected error while getting the method or property
> forSpreadsheet on object ScriptApp.TriggerBuilder.

For anyone that can help it is truly appreciated!

Happy new year and thanks again!

Comment: Try rewriting your AddRow function without using activate or activeRange.

Comment: What's the problem you have? What is your code doing compared to what you expect?

Comment: @Cooper do you know any alternatives to the 2 pieces of code you mentionned? Thanks!

Comment: Look [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet)

Comment: @Cooper thanks but that page is already my bible lol. I came to stackoverflow for some more concrete help. Thanks though.

Comment: Well I think the best thing that  you can do to improve your scripts is minimize your use of active and activeRange.  I'd suggest using them less than 1 percent of the time.

Comment: @Rafa Guillermo My Addrow script works as intended. Im currently running it manually though. ultimately I just want it to run everytime there is a form submission.

Comment: You don't need to create the trigger using the `onFormSubmit()` method, you can just set it up once and it will run automatically each time a form submission is made. If this Spreadsheet linked to a Google Form?

Comment: @RafaGuillermo So in reality i have 3 sheets. sheet 1 is my main sheet.

Sheet 2 takes data from the forms sheet and splits up the comma separated values that are in the forms sheet and puts them in individual cells. 

3rd sheet is the sheet that is linked directly to the form.

In sheet 1 the macro copies a template row that contains formulas in each cell. These formulas retrieve the data from sheet 2. 

I hope this clarifies my situation but if not ill try to explain in a different way

Comment: @Gab check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60714720/11551468) see if it helps